# How do conditionally reference a variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, reflection

This is kind of a strange question.  Basically there’s a const struct defined in a framework that I may or may not be able to load.  Let’s say the struct is called “ExternalStruct”.  I can tell whether or not I can load the framework but I can’t use the variable by name because if I can’t load the framework it will crash.  How can I do what I’m trying to do (reference ExternalStruct but only if I can load this framework)?

Thanks

EDIT:

My other thought was to use an ifdef but I’m not sure how those work with respect to compile time vs link time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the CFBundle/NSBundle for the library in question, once it's loaded you can use [CFBundleGetDataPointerForName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleGetDataPointerForName).

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I needed